# Modify tasks (afterEvaluate) in a single flavor Gradle

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, gradle

Currently I have two flavors in my gradle build: `googleplay` and `amazon`.

I'm using the multidex gradle solution and amazon requires to add the following task to the gradle build in order to save methods and apply their DRM:

```
android{
  ....
}


afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += "--set-max-idx-number=55000"

    }
}
```

How can I make that code only apply to the amazon flavor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at terminal output I found that usually standard android task name is combined from three parts:
*`task prefix`*+*`flavor name`*+*`build type`*
e.g.: `dexGoogleDebug`, `installGoogleDebug`, `assembleAmazonRelease`

So obvious solution would be just changing line `it.name.startsWith('dex')` to

```
    def name = it.name.toLowerCase()
    name.startsWith('dex') && name.contains('amazon')
```